# How to build boost::fiber alongside other boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build [boost::fiber](https://github.com/boostorg/fiber) alongside other boost libraries on Ubuntu. I downloaded boost version 1.61 from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.61.0/). And I downloaded version 1.0 of **boost::fiber** from github. I copied directory named *fiber* in *boost/libs* sub-directory in boost distribution. The command I used for building is:

```
sudo ./b2 cxxflags="-std=c++14" --build-type=minimal --build-dir=/home/bobeff/projects/build --layout=system install
```

The used version of g++ is:

> > g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609

**boost::fiber** failed to compile and the first of many errors is:

```
gcc.compile.c++ /home/bobeff/projects/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/fiber/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/algorithm.o
In file included from libs/fiber/src/algorithm.cpp:9:0:
./boost/fiber/fiber_context.hpp:91:5: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::context::execution_context’ without an argument list
     context::execution_context                      ctx_;
```

Comment: did you build and install boost::context? did you give boost::fiber the location of your boost installation?

Comment: As I wrote I build entire boost distribution alongside with *boost::fiber* added to the other libraries in *boost/libs* directory. *boost::context* is build successfully. But may be *boost::context* is not found when *boost::fiber* was being build. Do you know how to do it properly?

Comment: I have never built boost::fiber so can't help. I'm just thinking though, that the functionality offered by boost::fiber is already available in boost::coroutine isn't it?

Comment: *boost::coroutine* and *boost::fiber* are different libraries despite that they have some common use cases. You can see [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4024.pdf) article for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Did you build boost.context with C++14 too?
Check if all required C++-features (lambdas, nullptr etc.) are supported.
You see this at stdout when you run b2/bjam - maybe you have to call b2/bjam with option --reconfigure.
As an alternative you could wait till boost-1.62 is released (28.09.2016?).

Comment: You can see that I posted the build command and I used `cxxflags="-std=c++14"`. I think that this enables *C++14* with all included features, isn't it?

Comment: no, results of the configuration checks from previous runs are cached:
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_auto_declarations : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_constexpr : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_final : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_tuple : yes ...